# Why foreign movies have multiple Chinese dubs?

Tags: culture, movies, audio

I wanted to re-watch some movies I like in Chinese so I got Toy Story 1 and Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix. The thing is both of them have 3 audio tracks, 1 Cantonese and 2 Mandarin. I don't get why they would dub a movie to the same language (Mandarin) twice.

These 2 recordings are from the same scene in Toy Story
Track 1:
https://soundcloud.com/user-690602079/toy-story-s1-track-1?in=user-690602079/sets/mandarin
Track 2:
https://soundcloud.com/user-690602079/toy-story-s1-track-2?in=user-690602079/sets/mandarin

Another scene from Toy Story 
Track 1:
https://soundcloud.com/user-690602079/toy-story-s2-track-1?in=user-690602079/sets/mandarin
Track 2:
https://soundcloud.com/user-690602079/toy-story-s2-track-2?in=user-690602079/sets/mandarin

and these are from the same scene in Harry Potter
Track 1:
https://soundcloud.com/user-690602079/harry-potter-track-1?in=user-690602079/sets/mandarin
Track 2:
https://soundcloud.com/user-690602079/harry-potter-track-2?in=user-690602079/sets/mandarin

Are both of the tracks standard Mandarin ? Are they both legit dubs ?

Sorry for using a lot of links, idk what is the best practice when asking questions with audio samples like this.

Comment: Most likely that one is dubbed for Mainland China (PRC), and the other is dubbed for Taiwan (ROC). Mainland China also has restrictions on any sort of violence or sexual content, so the language might be changed to match the edited scenes.

Answer (score -1):

There are hundreds of dialects, which lead to some deviations in Mandarin accents in different regions, but are generally understood